# What is a good place to start learning about pulse jets?

Tags: jet-engine, engine-design

I'm a student who is curious about designing his own pulse jet engine, I am wondering if there are any schematics designs, notes, and other related materials I could/should study to learn about these engines. Where can I find such things and what is a good place to start?

Comment: I would start with Wikipedia [Pulsejet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulsejet). In the "External links" section, there are quite a number of links to specific resources.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try [this website on home made pulse jets](http://www.pulse-jets.com/) looks like it has some good info. [These guys are selling some plans](http://www.pulsejetengines.com/) and have info as well. Here is an [interesting instructables](http://www.instructables.com/id/Make-a-Pulse-jet-engine-Scanned-from-1958-plans/)... And here is [another DIY one](http://www.colinfurze.com/big-pulse-jet-project.html). You may also be able to dig up some of the work that was done with them during WWII with a bit of directed searching on some public archives (as it may be more or less public record now). Of course physics and engineering text books will always be of help but there may not be any pulse jet specific ones.

PSA: You should take extreme caution when building and testing something like this. You will presumably be burning jet fuel (or another comburent) in a home made combustion chamber which can lead to very bad things. Care should always be taken when firing up an engine (of any kinda) for the first time. Welds should be double checked, metal choice is important and please wear safety goggles!

Comment: Thanks a tonne! Had given some thought to studying the Argus engines used for The V1 bombers and Ford Cruise missiles, but this helps alot!

Comment: Be careful with the V1 bomb (AS014 Engine) those pulse jets were made to last for only one flight and a lot of corners were cut from a materials standpoint so i would not necessarily try to mimic it, the physics however will always apply.

Comment: On the crazy (also known as "don't try this at home") end of the scale, there's Colin Furze on youtube.

Answer (score 1):

If you look for performance data on the As-014 pulse jet, NACA did some thorough testing of it in 1945. The resulting report E5J02 can be found [here](http://naca.central.cranfield.ac.uk/reports/1945/naca-wr-e-269.pdf). It contains information about thrust, fuel flow, pressures and information about the test setup and procedure.

This [Russian site](http://www.airbase.ru/modelling/rockets/res/konstr/argus/argus_2.html) has lots of drawings and detail pictures.